# Matplotlib is shows old data mixed with new data on my chart, but Line2D.get_data() shows old data is deleted. Why does chart still show old data too?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

I have a class that handles plotting new data via an inbuilt PubSub-style functionality. When a publisher sets a new value, it causes a call to `update`:

```
def update(self, index, value):
    if index > len(self.values) - 1:
        print("Index exceeds length of chart values")
        raise
    else:
        self.values[index] = value
    # self.line is matplotlib.lines.Line2D, and self.fig is the figure, both created in __init__
    self.line.set_xdata(self.values)
    self.line.set_ydata([0 for v in self.values]) # I just want to see the x-dispersion of points
    self.fig.canvas.draw_idle()
    print(str(self.line.get_data()))
```

When I try:

```
chart.update(2, 3.14159)
chart.update(2, 2.71828)
```

I see that my data has been updated; the old data has been overwritten at index `2`. However, when the figure redraws, the new point is shown, but the old points remain too instead of being replaced! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not reproduce your behavior. There is always the same number of points visible and the update only affects the value at the corresponding index.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        self.values = [1, 2, 9]
        self.line = ax.plot(self.values, [0 for v in self.values], 
                            ls='', color='k', marker='o')[0]

    def update(self, index, value):
        if index > len(self.values) - 1:
            print("Index exceeds length of chart values")
            raise
        else:
            self.values[index] = value
        self.line.set_xdata(self.values)
        self.fig.canvas.draw_idle()
        print(str(self.line.get_data()))


test = Test()
test.update(index=1, value=5)
test.update(index=1, value=2)
```

Comment: You're right, I cannot reproduce it after restarting the notebook kernel. I can only assume that I must have been using an old class definition before the restart. Sorry to bother, and thank you for your answer.